# Split two sentences into words and characters and show them individually

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

Please help me to split TWO sentences into an array of words and characters and show them individually.

My input string is like this:

> If you didn't cry, I will give you sweets. Then I will give you
>   home-made cakes.

What I had done till now is given below:

```js
$(function() {
  generateWords();

  function generateWords() {
    $("#splitedWords").html("");
    var Input = "If you didn't cry, I will give you sweets. Then I will give you home-made cakes.";
    var outputArray = Input.split(/\s+/); // for spliting each word
    // for printing the sorted words inside a button
    for (var i = 0; i < outputArray.length; i++) {
      $("#splitedWords").append($('<span>' + outputArray[i] + '</span><br/>'));
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Input</h4>
  <p>If you didn't cry, I will give you sweets. Then I will give you home-made cakes.</p>
  <h4>O/P required <small>( Want to split words, dot, comma, hyphen, semicolon etc into an array)</small></h4>
  <p>
    var outputArray = [ "If", "you", "didn't", "cry", ",", "I", "will", "give", "you", "sweets", ".", "Then", "I", "will", "give", "you", "home-made", "cakes", "." ];
  </p>
  <h4>Actual O/P</h4>
  <p id="splitedWords"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Is I am in the right way? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: FYI jQuery is a library for amending the DOM, it's not useful in this scenario.

Comment: javascript has a split function. It won't get exactly what you want in this case but it is a good start. `var str = "your string"; str.split(" ");` .. See if this works for you

Comment: @depperm I will post what i had done so far, I had used JavaScript split method and reg-ex. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is splitting text into **tokens**. If you search, you'll find limitless solutions to this problem, as this is what most language parsers do in order to further analyze text. And I strongly suggest doing so, that's some useful stuff to be familiar with.

You can do it with a lot of methods, regex being one, but not the easiest of them.

```
[!#%&\'*+,\-./:;<=>?@\\\^_\`|~](?!\w)|[\"\)\(\]\[{}]|[^\s]*?(?=[!\"\#%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_\`{|}~]?(?:\s|$))
```

Is what I came up with on the spot with **all matches** being all of your **tokens**, as seen [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/yC8fW0/4), just put them into an array.

```
array = yourstring.match(/[!#%&\'*+,\-./:;<=>?@\\\^_\`|~](?!\w)|[\"\)\(\]\[{}]|[^\s]*?(?=[!\"\#%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_\`{|}~]?(?:\s|$))/)
```

should provide the results you're looking for.

Comment: I had used JavaScript split method and reg-ex for spiting the words. Its my mistake that I didn't posted what I had done so far. I will post it.

Comment: edited with the `string.match()` function, which should give you your desired result.

Comment: OK Andris I will try that.